# Compare and delete duplicate photos

Tags: python

I backup photos from my phone, camera one or two times per year. I think i have many duplicate photos in my backup directory.

I will find duplicates and remove this. Can i find duplicates with calculating the md5 sum? Or what is the correct way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a MD5 checksum should be fine for duplicates, in python this can be achieved by using the md5 library

```
import md5
data = open("filename", "rb").read() # The file
m = md5.new()
m.update(data)
print(m.digest())
```